# how can I use WM_GETMINMAXINFO in a c++ project?

Tags: c++, winapi, opencv, window

I have got a opencv window I'd like to modify with winapi. I would like to change the min of the window. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "I have got a opencv window"? Is your "c++ project" another process / application?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to instal a [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) with the `WH_CBT` value for the `idHook` parameter.

Quoting MSDN:

> HCBT_MOVESIZE A window is about to be moved or sized. wParam:
>   Specifies the handle to the window to be moved or sized. lParam:
>   Specifies a long pointer to a RECT structure containing the
>   coordinates of the window. By changing the values in the structure, a
>   CBTProc hook procedure can set the final coordinates of the window

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass the window, which means swapping the window procedure function pointer, handling the one message you're interested in, and forwarding all others to the original window procedure.

See MSDN [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.